# How to Create a cordova Plugin based off an existing XCode Project written in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an existing XCode project that I want to convert into an cordova plugin. I tried to google and see if there is somebody that already tried and documented this. Unfortunately I could not find anything. Are you aware of anything like that?

Comment: You don't create a plugin from an existing xcode project, you pick the classes you want to use on the plugin from the xcode project and copy them to the plugin folder

Comment: OK, and then I just add the cordova specific return types?

Comment: Read the plugin development guide, it's based on objective-c, but should help http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html. And search for swift plugins on github to take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate an XCode project that resides in your plugin into the Cordova app's XCode project by emplyoing hooks.

Assuming your plugin has an XCode project source dir in its subdirectory "deps", for instance "deps/CoolProject" (this would contain "deps/CoolProject/CoolProject.xcodeproj" as the actual XCode project file).

In plugin.xml inside the  `<platform name="ios">` tag:

```
<!-- these hooks simply copy over deps/CoolProject into the app's platforms/ios dir without integrating the files into the app's XCode project -->
<hook type="after_plugin_install" src="scripts/ios-install.sh" />
<hook type="before_plugin_uninstall" src="scripts/ios-uninstall.sh" />
<!-- and this links in the copied XCode project into the app's XCode project -->
<framework src="CoolProject/CoolProject.xcodeproj" type="projectReference"/>
```

scripts/ios-install.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

cp -a "$1"/plugins/<your-plugin-id>/deps/CoolProject "$1"/platforms/ios/
```

scripts/ios-uninstall.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf "$1"/platforms/ios/CoolProject
```